# Count DB rows since the start of this month

Tags: c#, sqlite

I wish to return the number of rows (count) of books where the month element of `DateTime` for `bookEntryTime` is this current month.

```
   public int GetMonthlyCount()
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var month = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
        var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
        return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE bookEntryTime > ?;", first);
    }
```

This query also counts books that were entered in the previous month. What is wrong with the query?

Comment: have you tried without `var first = month.AddMonths(-1);` ? looking for current month not last 30 days right?

Comment: this is really a pure sqlite question that has nothing to do with Xamarin

Comment: and as @Cfun points out you're explicitly including the previous month by doing `month.AddMonths(-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested by the current month and not the last 30 days (not 1 month period), remove this line:

```
 var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
```

Of course the parameter used is now `month`

```
return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE bookEntryTime > ?;", month );
```